# How to authenticate PythonScript task within Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PythonScript task within an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline that calls the Azure API to retrieve a list of subscriptions and management groups. My script is using the `DefaultAzureCredential` class, which I understand initially looks for certain environment variables (client ID, client secret and tenant ID), or can use a managed identity in order to authenticate. I can run my script locally, but I don't know how to set it up correctly so it works from the pipeline.

- If authenticating using the environment variables approach, how do I securely pass the required client and tenant variables to the script? Secret variables within a variable group cannot be used as environment variables.
- If authenticating using a managed identity, how do I tell the script which managed identity to use?

Any guidance gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with azure devops, but i do remember a colleague of mine once assigning a service principal to his Azure DevOps pipeline. I didn't ask to many questions; He was having an issue I was helping him with.

So for that part: https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/03/02/ManageIdentityInServiceConnections/
Maybe that is a step-forward into assigning the Managed Identity to your pipeline.

After you've assigned your pipeline to use the Managed Identity, the pipeline would automatically connect to the cloud with the service principal and find out what permissions it has to do what you want it to do. so don't forget to assign the Managed Identity permissions.

Now back to the bit of story background. My colleague's issue with the service principal and his Azure DevOps pipeline was that he needed to use the object id to assign the service principal. Supplying the client id made the pipeline fail.

If you want to go ahead with the ENV var approach. I would suggest using a Keyvault and pulling the secrets, then passing them on to your pipeline and using them. Again, I have no experience with Azure DevOps.
However, this is what I do in my Azure Functions and what you are trying seems very similar.
Maybe this would help with that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops